# How to query for an autonumber variable in msaccess from vb6?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I use the following code to look for many types of data, but now I am using it for an autonumeric field.

```
MyADORs.Open "SELECT Uso_CFDI FROM fact_CFDI WHERE ID = '" & adoCntctsRs!CFDI & "' ", Chazaro, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

And for some reason it does not work.

And I've tried lots of ways, always with the same result "Data type Mismatch in criteria expression"

```
MyADORs.Open "SELECT Uso_CFDI FROM fact_CFDI WHERE ID = '" & CInt(adoCntctsRs!CFDI) & "' ", Chazaro, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
MyADORs.Open "SELECT Uso_CFDI FROM fact_CFDI WHERE ID = '" & txtFields(0).txt & "' ", Chazaro, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

And I am getting out of ideas... Could please someone give some advice?

Thank you

Comment: If ID is a numeric field then you do not need the single quotes.

Comment: `MyADORs.Open "SELECT Uso_CFDI FROM fact_CFDI WHERE ID = " & adoCntctsRs!CFDI`

Comment: I would create your query in a separate string value, so you can inspect it in the debugger more easily. Then pass it to Open as a second step